# How to use decades in this sentence?

Tags: sentence, time, expression-choice

I want to say ongoing research on matter `X` using the word decades. The research started from the date of discovery of matter `x` in 1982 onwards. This should be an opening statement of an academic abstract.

My sentence is:

> Over three decades following its discovery, matter `x` has been a
>   focus of ongoing research worldwide.

or

> For over three decades following its discovery, matter `x` has been a
>   focus of ongoing research worldwide.

or

> For more than three decades following its discovery, matter `x` has
>   been a focus of ongoing research worldwide.

which one is more correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Over **the** three decades following its discovery...*

This is somewhere a determiner is necessary.

Comment: Good; perhaps better yet with "since" in lieu of "following."

Answer (score 0):

"For more than three decades..." or "For over three decades..." is appropriate. It's a prepositional phrase, so "for" is necessary.